# How to find the nth term of tribonacci series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to know the nth term of tibonacci series, given by the recurrence relation
$$
a_{n + 3} = a_{n + 2} + a_{n + 1} + a_n
$$
with $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2, a_3 = 4$, so the first few terms are
$$
1,2,4,7,13,24,44, \ldots
$$
I am more interested in derivation of how the nth term is calculated rather than direct comming up with black box formula.

Comment: The tribonacci numbers are generated by the homogeneous linear recurrence relation $T_n = T_{n-1}+T_{n-2}+T_{n-3}$. See the methods described in this wikipedia article for info on solving linear recurrence relations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation

Comment: I added the recurrence definition to your question, so people don't have to look it up themselves.

Comment: Do you know some method for the Fibonacci series? Have you tried something similar?

Comment: Yes there is Binet's methods to calculate nth term of fibonacci series.

Comment: Use linear algebra to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

The $n^{th}$ tribonacci number $T_n$ is given by the closest integer to $$\frac{3 b}{b^2-2 b+4} \Big(\frac{a_++a_-+1}{3}\Big)^n $$ where $$a_{\pm}=\sqrt[3]{19 \pm 3 \sqrt{33}}$$  $$b=\sqrt[3]{586 + 102 \sqrt{33}}$$

You could find all required information in the links the comments and answers refer to.

Answer (score 2):

See [OEIS sequence A000073](http://oeis.org/A000073). We can write
$$a_n = \sum_r \frac { -4\,{r}^{2}-3\,r+5}{
22\;{r}^{n+3}}$$
where the sum is over the three roots of $r^3 + r^2 + r - 1$ (one real
and two complex).