# Formula for the Tribonacci sequence

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Is there a formula for the Tribonacci sequence, where  the formula for Fibonacci is:

$$F_n=\frac{(1+\sqrt 5)^n-(1-\sqrt 5)^n)}{2^n\sqrt 5}.$$

Comment: A formula is given in [Wikipedia](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488) and various forms in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000073)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the nth term of tribonacci series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827565/how-to-find-the-nth-term-of-tribonacci-series)  Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41667/fibonacci-tribonacci-and-other-similar-sequences)