# find the nth fibonacci number where each number of is sum of last 3 numbers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

Using differential equations , I have seen some sites which solve the fibonacci number problem and give us a formula to find the nth fibonacci number.

Similarly I want to find the nth fibonacci number where each number is equal to "LAST THREE" numbers.

Example :

0 1 1 2 4 7 13 .....

How to get the exact formula to find the Nth fibonacci number by removing the recursion from it ?

```
F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) + F(n-3)
```

After solving the differential equations :

```
F(n) = Expression of constants which only depends on "n" .
```

What is the formula for F(n) ?

---

Also is it possible to get a formula to find the Nth fibonacci number where each number is equal to the sum of previous "M" numbers ?

```
F(n,m) = ???
```

Note : I am not a math student :/

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: This is called the Tribonacci sequence (I find that an amusing pun), and it's discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827565/how-to-find-the-nth-term-of-tribonacci-series

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: If the characteristic polynomial of the recurrence only has simple roots in $\mathbb{C}$ the main term has the form $$A_n = \sum_{k=1}^{d} C_k \zeta_k^n $$ where $\zeta_k$ ranges over the roots and $C_1,\ldots,C_d$ are constants depending on the initial values. This applies to the Fibonacci, Tribonacci, Tetranacci sequences etcetera.

Comment: An interesting side-question is to find efficient algorithms for the computation of $F_n, T_n$ or $Q_n$. As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2081213/how-many-digits-of-accuracy-will-an-answer-have/2081266#2081266) the computation of $F_n$ requires at most $2\log_2(n)$ multiplications.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions of these generalized Fibonacci problems rest on the resolution of the characteristic equation

$$r^m=r^{m-1}+r^{m-2}+\cdots r+1.$$
which can also be written
$$r^{m+1}-2r^{m}+1=0$$ 
or
$$1-2s+s^{m+1}=0$$
(where the solution $r=1$ must be discarded, and $s:=r^{-1}$). This equation has real as well as complex roots.
Hence the solution of the recurrence is a linear combination of terms $$(a\cos(n\omega)+b\sin(n\omega))e^{n\tau}$$ where the constants $a,b$ are determined from the initial terms of the sequence (which you forgot to specify) and $\tau,\omega$ are the real and imaginary parts of the roots.

Note that one of the roots clearly dominates the others in modulus, and tends to $2$ with increasing $m$. Hence for large $m$ and large $n$, the solution is close to

$$c2^n.$$

This is justified by

$$2^{m}\approx 2^{m-1}+2^{m-2}+\cdots 2+1.$$

[image]